# What is the function of the triangles and circles that appear in the ruler when working with text in Keynote?

Tags: keynote, text

I just discovered that two downward-facing triangles appear whenever I'm working with a text object in keynote; those serve to define the initial and final tabs. But I noticed that clicking on the ruler between these triangles creates additional shapes (left and right-facing triangles, a rhombus/diamond, and a circle). I've tried moving them around, but I haven't seen any change in the text. Maybe I don't know how to insert proper tabs while I'm typing. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer two are Margin guides [the edge of the printing area], the inner ones are Tab-stops; Markers that text & numbers will line up to if you separate them by using the Tab key instead of just some spaces.

[image]

The orange lines are mine, for illustration.
'Right tab' in the picture unfortunately has an accidental space after it, which stops it lining up with the orange line properly - my bad - but it illustrates that the space itself is included in the tab-stop.

You can see & edit a Tab function by right clicking a Tab marker...

[image]

BTW, if there's not enough room for the tabs, compared to the typed text, they simply don't [can't] work.

One last note - Tabs are set for that line only unless specified globally before you start typing, or if you Select All.